# Why documentation isn't showing when clicking on the attribute, shows on the window however

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea

**Screenshot:**

[image]

You can see when I press **`ctrl + j`** shortcut, the documentation appears in window but when I click on the attribute, it does take me to the source code, but there is no documentation. So, where that window documentation is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines you see on pressing **Ctrl + J** are getting description from predefined documentation block.
**@macro** is used to insert that peace of documentation.
Please, check that dart docs to understand it better https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc#macros.

So the doc template is located inside the `<your flutter_dir>/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart`
as:

```
/// {@template flutter.widgets.editableText.autocorrect}
/// Whether to enable autocorrection.
///
/// Defaults to true. Cannot be null.
/// {@endtemplate}
final bool autocorrect;
```